# The repository 'cdrom:/Ubuntu 18.04.4LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20200203.1) bionic Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: 18.04, updates, software-center, update-manager

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04. After this, my system is not detecting my Wi-Fi. My wireless adapter is an Intel 7265.

I watched some YouTube videos about this issue, which all suggested that I should update my drivers using Software & Updates. But just like others, I did not get this option *Installable from CD-ROM/DVD*.  As you can see I didn't get any options.

[image: Software & Updates 1]

[image: Software & Updates 2]

After I tried to update, GNOME Software shows:

```
The repository 'cdrom:/Ubuntu 18.04.4LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20200203.1) bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
```

the above title message. What should I do?

Comment: Your installation media won't help you, as it seems from your title that it was *bionic* (18.04) and not *focal*.

Comment: @karlom it's not in fstab, but in sources.list most likely, but you can find and disable (remove checkbox) in the update-manager boxes likely easier (if preferred).